# How to replace certain URLs with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a website with URLs like this:

```
www.website.com/user/page/someName1
www.website.com/user/page/someName2
www.website.com/user/page/someName3
```

How can I remove or hide /user/page with .htaccess to end up with this:

```
www.website.com/someName1
www.website.com/someName2
www.website.com/someName3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+user/page/(\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^user/page/(.+)$ /$1 [L,NC]
```