# Replace url text with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

The url of my app is `http://example.com/public/login`. I want my url to be `http://example.com/account/login`.

How do I replace text with .htaccess

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015597/how-to-replace-certain-urls-with-htaccess) hides the text only. But I need to replace the text

Comment: You "app" consists only of that single URL?

Answer (score 0):

If you really only want to redirect that specific URL, then this should do the work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?public/login$ /account/login [R=301,END]
RewriteRule ^/?account/login$ /public/login [END]
```

If your "app" actually consists of more than just that single URL you will have to modify your question and add more precise details...

For above rule set to work you have to implement it either in the http server's host configuration or, if that is not possible for you, in a distributed configuration file (".htaccess"). In the second case you also need to make sure that the interpretation of such files is actually enabled and the rules are implemented in the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder of your host. See the excellent documentation for more details and good examples: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).